How to remap the windows copilot key in Ubuntu?
I have a Dell laptop (inspiron 16 5645). In addition to the Super key, it has another key which I am told is the windows co-pilot key. It appears to behave like the left-shift key, and xev reports it as the same keycode, but presumably Windows can distinguish it.
Can I do anything useful with it? I want to map it to right-ctrl, which is absent.
Edit: terminal output added:-
Outer window is 0x800001, inner window is 0x800002
PropertyNotify event, serial 8, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    atom 0x27 (WM_NAME), time 74036986, state PropertyNewValue
PropertyNotify event, serial 9, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    atom 0x22 (WM_COMMAND), time 74036986, state PropertyNewValue
PropertyNotify event, serial 10, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    atom 0x28 (WM_NORMAL_HINTS), time 74036986, state PropertyNewValue
CreateNotify event, serial 11, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    parent 0x800001, window 0x800002, (10,10), width 50, height 50
border_width 4, override NO
PropertyNotify event, serial 14, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    atom 0xf9 (WM_PROTOCOLS), time 74036986, state PropertyNewValue
MapNotify event, serial 15, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    event 0x800001, window 0x800002, override NO
ConfigureNotify event, serial 21, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    event 0x800001, window 0x800001, (0,0), width 178, height 178,
    border_width 0, above 0x600109, override NO
PropertyNotify event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    atom 0x16f (_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS), time 74036986, state PropertyNewValue
PropertyNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    atom 0x153 (_MUTTER_NEEDS_FRAME), time 74036986, state PropertyNewValue
PropertyNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    atom 0x101 (_NET_WM_DESKTOP), time 74036986, state PropertyNewValue
PropertyNotify event, serial 31, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    atom 0x13b (WM_STATE), time 74036987, state PropertyNewValue
PropertyNotify event, serial 31, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    atom 0x107 (_NET_WM_STATE), time 74036987, state PropertyNewValue
PropertyNotify event, serial 31, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    atom 0x131 (_GTK_EDGE_CONSTRAINTS), time 74036987, state PropertyNewValue
ConfigureNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    event 0x800001, window 0x800001, (50,32), width 178, height 178,
    border_width 0, above 0x600109, override NO
PropertyNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    atom 0x131 (_GTK_EDGE_CONSTRAINTS), time 74036988, state PropertyNewValue
ReparentNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    event 0x800001, window 0x800001, parent 0xa001a0,
    (0,0), override NO
PropertyNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    atom 0xfe (_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS), time 74037001, state PropertyNewValue
ConfigureNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    event 0x800001, window 0x800001, (14,49), width 178, height 178,
    border_width 0, above 0xa001a1, override NO
MapNotify event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    event 0x800001, window 0x800001, override NO
VisibilityNotify event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    state VisibilityUnobscured
Expose event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    (0,0), width 178, height 10, count 3
Expose event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    (0,10), width 10, height 58, count 2
Expose event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    (68,10), width 110, height 58, count 1
Expose event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    (0,68), width 178, height 110, count 0
ConfigureNotify event, serial 35, synthetic YES, window 0x800001,
    event 0x800001, window 0x800001, (198,217), width 178, height 178,
    border_width 2, above 0x0, override NO
PropertyNotify event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    atom 0x107 (_NET_WM_STATE), time 74037002, state PropertyNewValue
FocusIn event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyNonlinear
KeymapNotify event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
PropertyNotify event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    atom 0x107 (_NET_WM_STATE), time 74037005, state PropertyNewValue
PropertyNotify event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    atom 0x107 (_NET_WM_STATE), time 74037005, state PropertyNewValue
EnterNotify event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    root 0x3d1, subw 0x0, time 74037005, (155,114), root:(355,333),
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyNonlinear, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0
KeymapNotify event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
PropertyNotify event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    atom 0x107 (_NET_WM_STATE), time 74037016, state PropertyNewValue
KeyRelease event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    root 0x3d1, subw 0x0, time 74037112, (155,114), root:(355,333),
    state 0x0, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) "
"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    root 0x3d1, subw 0x0, time 74043466, (155,114), root:(355,333),
    state 0x40, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    root 0x3d1, subw 0x0, time 74043594, (155,114), root:(355,333),
    state 0x41, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
LeaveNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x800001,
    root 0x3d1, subw 0x0, time 74047709, (-12,-47), root:(188,172),
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0
ClientMessage event, serial 38, synthetic YES, window 0x800001,
    message_type 0xf9 (WM_PROTOCOLS), format 32, message 0xf7 (WM_DELETE_WINDOW)


Apparently it's supposed to be LShift+Super (Windows)+F23: https://www.windowscentral.com/software-apps/windows-11/the-secret-behind-the-windows-11-copilot-key-is-that-it-isnt-a-new-key-at-all

@DavidDE Seems to be a valid key remapping question to me. Please post the terminal output into your original question of the xev output of a shift press and shift release and the cp press and cp release.  Keycodes may be the same, but keysyms may differ.

Original post edited. (Surely this is not a windows post). Ubuntu 24.04

Please add terminal output as text (cut and paste) to your original posting, using code tags to keep formatting.  I see only one key (shift?) press and release in the image you posted -- don't see the copilot key press and release for comparison.

I have pasted the full terminal session. I believe the 2 keycode 50 events at the only output from the press and release of the copilot key. This suggests it's a left-shift. But my question is, if so, how does windows distinguish it?


the windows copilot key equal leftshift+leftmeta in ubuntu.
you can test it by evsieve.

you can remap copilot key by keyd.
add bottom line into configure file of keyd.


leftshift+leftmeta = overload(control, esc)

keyd
rvaiya/keyd: A key remapping daemon for linux.
keyd quick start
https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd?tab=readme-ov-file#quickstart

Thanks @Chase chen. This sounds a simple solution. What and where is the configuration file?

config file of keyd.
rvaiya/keyd: A key remapping daemon for linux.

Thanks, @chase chen. Perfect.

where is that config file to insert that line?

https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd?tab=readme-ov-file#quickstart

To map the Copilot key to right-ctrl on my Dell Precision running Ubuntu 24.04 I installed keyd from the ppa, created /etc/keyd/default.conf with the following mapping: leftshift+leftmeta = rightcontrol under the [main] section.

Much appreciated for the helpful and quick solution, worked for me!

So i had the a similar problem except being an arch user and having a lenovo with a copilot key.
What worked for me is the following script (after installing evsieve):
sudo setkeycodes 6e 193 #Catch unknown keycode and make it into left-meta
sudo /usr/bin/evsieve\
     --input "/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd" grab=auto persist=exit\ #Setup keyboard
     --hook key:leftmeta key:leftshift key:f23 sequential period=0.032 send-key=key:leftctrl\ #Capture left-meta, left-shift and f23 (the copilot button as it is now) and produce a leftctrl
     --withhold key:leftmeta key:leftshift key:f23\ #Don't send copilot button
     --output create-link="/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd-evsieve" #More keyboard things - i think

And the original (i failed to run with comments in bash):
sudo setkeycodes 6e 193
sudo /usr/bin/evsieve\
     --input "/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd" grab=auto persist=exit\
     --hook key:leftmeta key:leftshift key:f23 sequential period=0.032 send-key=key:leftctrl\
     --withhold key:leftmeta key:leftshift key:f23\
     --output create-link="/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd-evsieve" #More keyboard things - i think


Thanks @TheBlackKoala. This looks perfect. INstalled successfully, but I must admit that your script leaves me cross-eyed. When I run it nothing discernable happens. But there's so much in there I don't understand, and I don't know what I need to change to reflect my setup (eg the keycodes). Can you talk me through what the script is doing, please.

@Pansmanser Sure. I will add some context inline - and this is my reference where i found the code if you want more info:
https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/1dnh6ge/comment/lhkoy5h/

Still a bit mystified by this, @TheBlackKoala. Where did keycode 6e come from? Copilot generates 50, reported by XEV, or 125+42 by showkey on my system. Nor do I recognise the string "/dev/...kbd". I see obhjt these are the same as Ran_Cossack's answer. Do I need to change these to match my system?

@Pansmanser so i just tried out without the setkeycodes and it does not work after a reboot. It captures some weird code emitted by the copilot button and transforms it into something that is easier to work with.
I'm pretty sure the kbd-device-paths are for the input to capture from (builtin input) and the output to send it to.

@Pansmanser i forgot to add that the weird keycode can be seen using showkey -s. From what i can tell it's just garbage they have added to make the copilot key unique.

Here are the steps I did to remap "copilot key" to right control in Ubuntu 22.04.

Install keyd from ppa

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:keyd-team/ppa
sudo apt update


Create default config file, /etc/keyd/default.conf, with contents


[ids]

*

[main]

leftshift+leftmeta = rightcontrol


Reload config: sudo keyd reload

I had to reboot in this step because a lock file was blocking keyd to reload.



